# IIS Port error?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am having an when i am changing my `IIS server` from `IIS` Express to `Local IIS`.It is showing me following error:

```
"Unable to create vitual directory.The site for the URL `'http://localhost/App1'` exists on both the localIIS web server and IIS web server.You need to edit the 'C:\Users\IISExpress\config\appllicationhost.config' file to change the port number in use by IIS express or use IIS manager to change the site's binding(s) in IIS".
```

When i click on `Create Virtual Directory` it gives above error how to solve it ?

Comment: You are creating a website with port which already exists on IIS express..use a different port no. or delete the old website.

Comment: Try closing IISExpress worker process first.